# Java "Duplicate local variable " and "cannot convert from String to Module"

Tags: java, minecraft

1:
Duplicate local variable:

So I am kind of new to Programming / Java and I tried to code a small client in mcp (Minecraft mod coder pack) and first off: *I know that it is against the terms of service, but I am only using it to become a better coder and I will not sell the client or give it to anyone else.*

So I got these weird errors when ever I try to toggle all mods on command : http://prnt.sc/cw9ys0

```
      Module m;
  if (messageLow.startsWith(".t")) {
    try
    {
      String input = messageLow.substring(3);
      for (Iterator localIterator = Boi.moduleManager.mods.iterator(); localIterator.hasNext();)
      {
        m = (Module)localIterator.next();
        if (m.name.toLowerCase().equals(input)) {
          m.toggleMod();
        }
      }
    }
    catch (Exception localException) {}
  }
  if ((messageLow.equalsIgnoreCase(".a")) || (messageLow.equalsIgnoreCase(".all"))) {
    for (Module m : Boi.moduleManager.mods) {
      if ((!m.isEnabled) && 
        (!m.isMinimod)) {
        m.toggleMod();
```

Maybe I am just acting stupid but I don't think I can just rename them to m1

2:
cannot convert from String to Module:

So on this one I am trying to change settings on command, but this error keeps on poppin up: http://prnt.sc/cwa0wq

```
String input = messageLow.substring(12);
      switch ((m = input).hashCode())
```

I am sorry if something is not made clear enough, I'll answer it in the comments!

Comment: Please post relevant code here, do not expect us to look at screenshots.

Comment: please include the code as text inside the question.

Comment: I just used the Screenshots so you can see the errors, sorry!

Comment: Errors mean exactly what they says :) you can't have two variables with same name in one scope and can't assign `Module` to `String`.

Comment: `catch (Exception localException) {}` is pretty straightforward way to trouble :)

Answer (score 2):

1. You redefined a variable `m`, it is in the first line of the code and then again in the `for` loop: `for (Module m : Boi.moduleManager.mods) {--`
2. You tried to assign a String variable `input` into a Module variable `m`, pay attention to `m = input` part within the `switch` command. That is not allowed in Java.

Comment: So, ist there a alternative for the second one?

Comment: @ZuckerKuchen In order to answer that, we should see the definition of the class `Module` and the explanation about what are you trying to achieve there. At first glance, it seems that `input.hashCode()` would be OK to put within `switch` command (without any `m = input` stuff), assuming that you want to perform switch-case on `hashCode()` of the input string.